# XAML PivotTable from Mosha Pasumansky

Tags: c#, wpf, olap, pivot-table

Does anyone have sources of his pivot table? Sources were hosted at http://wpf.netfx3.com/files/folders/5672/download.aspx, but now this site is down. Or may be there are similar samples of pivot grid(with source)?

Here is a pic of it : [image: XAML PivotTable]

Comment: Please anyone! It was decommissioned Jan 5 2009: http://www.ssas-info.com/analysis-services-client-tools-frontend/146-xaml-based-pivottable-control - ping me if you have a copy, thanks!

Comment: Edit I've written to a couple of people now (Darren Gosbell) and they dont have copies. I couldn't get in contact with Mosha, he must have moved on from MSFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in response to "Similar Samples of Pivot Grid (with Source)"

CellSetGrid is an Open Source ASP .Net (c#) control, which offers pivot table like functionality.

[This used to be available for download in this site:

www.SQLServerAnalysisServices.com

Now the site does not host this control anymore.]

I have uploaded the source of the control - CellSetGrid here.
http://www.box.net/shared/6gi0n79q6t

1) You can build the source 2) Add this as a Control in Visual Studio toolbox. 3) Drag and Drop control to a web form 4) Set the connection string to the cube 5) This will show all the dimensions and measure groups so you can drag n drop what you want to get a pivot table like functionality

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need this by here is the [link](http://windowsclient.net/downloads/folders/controlgallery/entry2351.aspx).